# CSS: how to remove the indent of list items shown in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am puzzled by this. The first line of a list item has some indent in Firefox, but not in other browsers. Here is the jsfiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/Lekdkj4o/

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul style="width:200px">
<li>blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS (extracted from a project)

```
ul {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

ul {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    left: -30px;
    position: relative;
}
li {
    list-style: none inside none;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}

ul {
    font-size: 0.95em;
    list-style: disc outside none;
    padding-left: 4.2em;
}

ul {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 2.8em;
}
```

How can I remove the indent shown in Firefox?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your styles on the li to be:

```
list-style: none outside none;
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lekdkj4o/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can target specific browsers with CSS code:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/

You can add a negative margin when using firefox browsers specifically using the above technique. That shoudl fix your issue.

Edit: depending on what exactly you want to achieve as a final result, you may want to use the text-indent css property if it's just the first line that is causing you problems. (sorry I don't have firefox installed at the moment son I can't confirm this)